# Do lots of <Table> tags put a strain on DOM?

Tags: html

One of my supervisors suggested that I shouldn't use `<table>` tags in a particular case of my UI.

I was only generating a few cells to wrap around and structure some content and because if the web-page has too many `<table>` tags, traversing the DOM could be slow such as using Document.SelectByID methods.

I don't think this is true but at the same time, I can't find opinions on it. What does everyone else think?

Comment: More importantly, are you only using `table` tags for tabular data? If you are using them for anything else, the [chances are you shouldn't be.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84986/4665)

Comment: Yes. If you have a huge amount of tags(not just <table>) your page will be slower. Slower to load, to traverse etc.. Maybe you should genereate html code dynamically.

Comment: I thought so as much Antony, thanks alot both! Switching to flexboxes. The <table> tags were reactJS components that were used on the same page several times just to add some situational context